# AWS CLI - is there a way to extract tar.gz from S3 to home without storing the tar.gz?

Tags: amazon-web-services, amazon-s3

To elaborate,

There is a tar.gz file on my AWS S3, let's call it **example.tar.gz**.

So, what I want to do is download the extracted contents of **example.tar.gz** to **/var/home/**.

One way to do it is to simply download the tar.gz, extract it, then delete the tar.gz.

However, I don't want to use space downloading the tar.gz file, I just want to download the extracted version or only store the extracted version.

Is this possible?

Thanks!

Comment: if my answer has worked for you, please mark it as the "best answer" i.stack.imgur.com/QpogP.png

Answer (score 30):

What you need is the following:

`aws s3 cp s3://example-bucket/file.tar.gz - | tar -xz`

This will **stream** the `file.tar.gz` from s3 and extract it directly (in-memory) to the current directory. No temporary files, no extra storage and no clean up after this one command.

*Make sure you write the command exactly as above.*

Comment: @bow it should extract the file in the current directory. If you did "ls -al" you should find the extracted files there

Comment: To a specific folder, aws s3 cp s3://example-bucket/file.tar.gz - | tar -xz -C /var/home/

Answer (score 0):

Today I tested with Python Boto 3 and aws cli and I noticed that tar.gz is extracted automatically when the file is downloaded

Comment: I noticed something similar but that happened only one day, I think they were testing a functionality. atm I don't know if they will include a flag or something that  enable/disable auto extract. But I'm prety sure tht will be available soon. I noticed that because everyday I download a file using boto 3 and I had the problem just one day now I have to extract it manually

Answer (score -2):

There isn't currently a way you can do this with S3.

You could create the following script though and just run it whenever you wish to download the tar. Just as long as you have the IAM role / access keys setup.

```
!#/bin/bash
aws s3 cp s3://$1/$2 $3
tar -xvf $3
rm $3
```

Then just call the script using `./myScript BUCKET_NAME FILE_LOCATION OUTPUT_FILE`

Comment: This will create a tar file locally, extract the tar file to disk (using diskspace = tar file + uncompressed files) then delete the tar file.